# TableView collapsing cell while scrolling to another: weird behavior

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, cell

I have a tableView with chat bubbles.

---

Those bubbles are shortened if the `character count` is `more than 250`

If a user clicks on a bubble

- The previous selection gets deselected (shortened)
- The new selection expands and reveals the whole content
- The new selections top constraint changes *(from 0 to 4)*

---

## What I would like to achieve?

> If a long bubble is selected already, but the user selects another bubble, I want the tableView to scroll to the position of the new selected bubble.

I'll share a video about it

Without this scrolling, the contentOffset remains the same and it looks bad.

**(In the video: on the right)**

---

**Video:**

> **Right:** without the mentioned scrolling
>
> **Left:** with scrolling

https://youtu.be/_-peZycZEAE

---

**Here comes the problem:**

On the left, you can notice that it is glitchy.

- Random ghost cells are appearing for no reason.
- Sometimes it even messes up the height of some bubbles (not in the video)

## Why is it so?

**Code:**

```
func bubbleTappedHandler(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        
        let touchPoint = sender.location(in: self.tableView)
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {
            
            if indexPath == currentSelectedIndexPath {

                // Selected bubble is tapped, deselect it
                self.selectDeselectBubbles(deselect: indexPath)

            } else {
                if (currentSelectedIndexPath != nil){

                    // Deselect old bubble, select new one
                    self.selectDeselectBubbles(select: indexPath, deselect: currentSelectedIndexPath)
                    
                } else {

                    // Select bubble
                    self.selectDeselectBubbles(select: indexPath)

                }
            }

        }
    }
    
    
    
    func selectDeselectBubbles(select: IndexPath? = nil, deselect: IndexPath? = nil){
        
        
        var deselectCell : WorldMessageCell?
        var selectCell : WorldMessageCell?
        
        if let deselect = deselect {
            deselectCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: deselect) as? WorldMessageCell
        }
        if let select = select {
            selectCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: select) as? WorldMessageCell
        }
        
        
        // Deselect Main
        if let deselect = deselect, let deselectCell = deselectCell {

            tableView.deselectRow(at: deselect, animated: false)
            currentSelectedIndexPath = nil
            // Update text
            deselectCell.messageLabel.text = self.dataSource[deselect.row].message.shortened()

            
        }
        // Select Main
        if let select = select, let selectCell = selectCell {

            tableView.selectRow(at: select, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
            currentSelectedIndexPath = select
            // Update text
            deselectCell.messageLabel.text = self.dataSource[select.row].message.full()
        }
        
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: appSettings.defaultAnimationSpeed) {
                
            // Deselect Constraint changes
            
            if let deselect = deselect, let deselectCell = deselectCell {
                // Constarint change
                deselectCell.nickNameButtonTopConstraint.constant = 0
                deselectCell.timeLabel.alpha = 0.0
                deselectCell.layoutIfNeeded()
                
            }
            
            // Select Constraint changes
            if let select = select, let selectCell = selectCell {
                
                // Constarint change
                selectCell.nickNameButtonTopConstraint.constant = 4
                selectCell.timeLabel.alpha = 1.0
                selectCell.layoutIfNeeded()
                
                
            }
            
            
        }

        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
        
        
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: appSettings.defaultAnimationSpeed) {
            if let select = select, deselect != nil, self.tableView.cellForRow(at: deselect!) == nil && deselectCell != nil {

                // If deselected row is not anymore on screen
                // but was before the collapsing,
                // then scroll to new selected row  

                self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: select, at: .top, animated: false)
            }
        }

    }
```

---

## Update 1: Added Github project

**Link:** https://github.com/krptia/test2

I made a small version of my app, so that you can see and test what my problem is. I would be so thankful if someone could help to solve this issue! :c

Comment: When you are scrolling, it's redrawing the cells and if you don't handle the cells to store state it was in, it will draw the initial state.

Comment: @carbonr thank you for your response! What can I do about this to make it smooth?:c

Comment: One thing is important here. You are using a tap gesture recogniser for selection detection. Is cell selection enabled on the tableView and are you implementing the `didSelectRow` method of the `UITableViewDelegate` also?

Comment: @Adeel Selection is enabled, but I am not implementing the `didSelectRow` method. I created my own "selection system": Because I only want the selection to happen when the user clicks exactly on the bubble (This is why I made a delegate (for `bubbleTappedHandler`), and why I have the `currentSelectedIndexPath` variable. Actually there's no need for me to use `tableView.selectRow(at: ...)` and `tableView.deselectRow(at: ...)`, so yeah, I'll just delete those line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's define what we mean by "without scrolling" - we mean that the cells more of less stay the same.  So we want to find a cell that we want to be the anchor cell.  From before the changes to after the changes the distances from the cell's top to the top of the screen is the same.

```
var indexPathAnchorPoint: IndexPath?
var offsetAnchorPoint: CGFloat?

func findHighestCellThatStartsInFrame() -> UITableViewCell? {
  return self.tableView.visibleCells.filter {
     $0.frame.origin.y >= self.tableView.contentOffset.y
  }.sorted {
     $0.frame.origin.y > $1.frame.origin.y
  }.first
}

func setAnchorPoint() {
  self.indexPathAnchorPoint = nil;
  self.offsetAnchorPoint = nil;

  if let cell = self.findHighestCellThatStartsInFrame() {
    self.offsetAnchorPoint = cell.frame.origin.y - self.tableView.contentOffset.y
    self.indexPathAnchorPoint = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
  }
}
```

we call this before we start doing stuff.

```
 func bubbleTappedHandler(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.setAnchorPoint()
     ....
```

Next we need to set the content offset after we are doing doing our changes so that the cell moves back to where it is suppose to.

```
func scrollToAnchorPoint() {
  if let indexPath = indexPathAnchorPoint, let offset = offsetAnchorPoint {
    let rect = self.tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
    let contentOffset = rect.origin.y - offset
    self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: contentOffset), animated: false)
  }
}
```

Next we call it after we are done doing our changes.

```
  self.tableView.beginUpdates()
  self.tableView.endUpdates()
  self.tableView.layoutSubviews()
  self.scrollToAnchorPoint()
```

The animation can be a little strange because there is a lot going on at the same time.  We are changing the content offset and the sizes of the cell at the same time, but if you place your finger next to the first cell that top is visible you will see it ends up in the correct place.

Comment: This works excellent! Thank you for your response! Yes, the animation is a bit strange but this is the best that can be achieved, thank you very much! One question: the tableView jumps for a second when a long bubble is deselected on the top, and a smaller one is selected below it. Is it possible to fix the jumping by just reloading the tableView? I'm experimenting with it..

Comment: I don't know. Something that you can try to slow down the animation in the entire app so you can see exactly what the animation is doing.  UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.layer.speed = 0.5

Answer (score 0):

Try using this `willDisplay` api on `UITableViewDelegate`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (indexPath == currentSelectedIndexPath) {
        // logic to expand your cell
        // you don't need to animate it since still not visible
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code for bubbleTappedHandler with this and run and check:

```
func bubbleTappedHandler(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let touchPoint = sender.location(in: self.tableView)
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {

        if indexPath == currentSelectedIndexPath {
            currentSelectedIndexPath = nil
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        } else {
            if (currentSelectedIndexPath != nil){
                if let prevSelectedIndexPath = currentSelectedIndexPath {
                    currentSelectedIndexPath = indexPath
                    tableView.reloadRows(at: [prevSelectedIndexPath, indexPath], with: .automatic)
                }
            } else {
                currentSelectedIndexPath = indexPath
                tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            }

        }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1, execute: { [weak self] in
            let currentIndexPath = self?.currentSelectedIndexPath ?? indexPath
            self?.tableView.scrollToRow(at: currentIndexPath, at: .top, animated: false)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this does not solve the problem :c

Comment: The animation is not smooth, even fuzzier with the reloadRows method you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You can use **tableView?.scrollToRow**. For example

```
let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) // put your selected indexpath and section here 
yourTableViewName?.scrollToRow(at: newIndexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: true) // give the desired scroll position to tableView
```

Available scroll positions are **.none**, **.top**, **.middle**, **.bottom**

Answer (score 0):

This glitch is because of a small mistake. Just do these 2 things and the issue will be resolved.

1. Set tableView's `rowHeight` and `estimatedRowHeight` in `viewDidLoad

   ```
   tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 316 // Value taken from your project. This may be something else
   tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
   ```
2. Remove the `estimatedHeightForRowAt` and `heightForRowAt` delegate methods from your code.

Comment: Tried what you wrote, but it still does produce the problem. I updated the Github with your solution, check it out: Click on the long one, then scroll down (so that the long one is still visible at the top, but the smaller one is too): and click one the smaller one. It is weirdly animated